# Parsing and creating a dict python

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to create a dict by parsing a string

```
<brns ret = "Herld" other = "very">
<brna name = "ame1">
```

I would like to create a dict that has the following key-value pairs:

```
dict = {'brnsret': 'Herld', 
        'brnsother':'very',
        'brnaname':'ame1'}
```

I have a working script that can handle this:

```
<brns ret = "Herld">
<brna name = "ame1">
```

my Code to generate the dict:

```
match_tag = re.search('<(\w+)\s(\w+) = \"(\w+)\">', each_par_line)
if match_tag is not None:


   dict_tag[match_tag.group(1)+match_tag.group(2)] = match_tag.group(3)
```

But how should I tweak my script to handle more than one attribute  pair in a tag?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try split the input by space and use list.index() to find `'='`, get the index (say, a) and generate dict with left and right operand (i.e. in the list, at a-1, a+1) of equals sign? (since I'm not so familiar with regex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative option and, probably, just for educational reasons - you can pass this kind of string into a lenient *HTML parser* like [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<brns ret = "Herld" other = "very">
<brna name = "ame1">
"""

d = {tag.name + attr: value
     for tag in BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")()
     for attr, value in tag.attrs.items()}
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'brnaname': 'ame1', 'brnsother': 'very', 'brnsret': 'Herld'}
```